# How to refresh MKMapView in the appDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

Initially when I learned how to write a multi view application I found this handy way to reload the UITableView

[randomTableView reloadData];

But when I want to reload an MKMapView how would I do this exactly?  The scenario is this:

I pick an address and the map loads (hits all the usual controller methods - life is good)
Next I go "back" and click another address (yet the map is still showing the previous location)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How and in what controller method does the map load the first address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the `MKMapView`'s center coordinate (`setCenterCoordinate:animated:`) or its region (`setRegion:animated:`). You probably do it already with the first call to the map -- you'll just need to do it again.